# MS SQL Server 2000 - триггер на подсчет суммы двух полей разных типов

Tags: sql-server

Помогите написать триггер, пожалуйста, для вычисления суммы полей типа DateTime и Int

Comment: Вы сами понимаете, что Вам надо?

Answer (score 1):

И в чем возникает сложность? Примерно так:

Схема таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SumTrigger](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [opendate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [expired] [int] NOT NULL,
    [closedate] [datetime] NULL)
GO
```

Триггер:

```
USE SportsStore
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('SportsStore.dbo.sTrigger','TR') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TRIGGER sTrigger 
GO

CREATE TRIGGER sTrigger 
   ON  SumTrigger 
   AFTER INSERT
   AS 
        UPDATE SumTrigger SET closedate = inserted.opendate + inserted.expired 
        FROM inserted 
GO
```

Comment: Это сумма разных типов данных? Или все таки добавление к DateTime суток?

Comment: @Oleg53, по существу, это сумма разных типов данных. При сложении разных типов, если это возможно, происходит неявное приведение к одному типу, а если нет, то ошибка. В данном случае тип int неявно приводится к типу datetime и происходит потом сложение двух дат. Можно было бы сделать это явно через cast: `cast(inserted.expired as datetime)`. Для примера `SELECT cast(5 as datetime)` выдаст `1900-01-06 00:00:00.000`, что потом при сложении просто прибавит пять дней. Если нужны не сутки, то тогда уже придется использовать DATEADD для суммы, но никаких особых требований в вопросе не указано.

Comment: Все это понятно. НО.. Формулировка не корректная. Например, в данном случае (MS SQL Server), добавляются сутки. Реально разрешение 1 мс. И вообще, "сумма разных типов данных" мне бьет по ушам. Исключение - числовые типы данных. Это, например, как дату суммировать с апельсинами. Просто ЗДЕСЬ подошел частный случай.